# How do I set default selected value in Struts2 <s:select> tag?

Tags: struts2, html-select, struts-tags

I am new in Struts2. I have user form, role column have a drop-down list. When user form is in edit mode, the stored values are placed into corresponding controls. But I can't set drop-down list by default selected value. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Nate's answer, I've found that I need to put apostrophes around the data in the value attribute if the key type is a String in order for it to recognize that my input value is a String.

Comment: Saved my day. Much thanks to you ! So `value="'helloworld"` works and not `value="helloworld` really weird syntax

Answer (score 6):

If the value in your select tag matches a key from the list in the select tag, Struts will do the correct thing and make that value the default.  Note that the types must match.

https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html

Comment: Broken link 321

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate this in an example :

```
<s:select name="employee.course.courseId" value="3"  label="%{getText('label.courseName')}" list="courses" listKey="courseId" listValue="courseName" />
```

- Here the Employee object contains an object called "course" and it has
  a property "courseId"
- listKey is selected as courseId and the listValue is selected as
  courseName
- Hence the output will be like :

  ```
      <option value="1">Computer Science</option>
      <option value="2">Electronics</option>
      <option value="3">Mechanical</option>
  ```
- The value attribute is set to "3" and it matches the 3rd attribute in
  the list, which is Mechanical
- Therefore this will be the default selected value in the dropdown,
  hence the output html will be like :

  ```
      <option value="1">Computer Science</option>
      <option value="2">Electronics</option>
      <option value="3" selected="selected">Mechanical</option>
  ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you follow everything correctly and it doesn't preselect then you need to make sure that return type of the key matches.
e.g. for following list

```xml
<select onchange="showHideDefDiv('typeListId')" style="selectCss50" class="selectCss50" id="typeListId" name="definitionDiv_I">
  <option value="blank"> </option>
  <option selected="selected" value="definitionDiv_I">I</option>
</select>

<s:select list="%{editRulePojo.groupPojoList}" listKey="%{groupType}"
          listValue="%{groupTypeValue}" value='definitionDiv_I' />
```

doesn't work, while

```xml
<s:select list="%{editRulePojo.groupPojoList}" listKey="%{groupType}"
          listValue="%{groupTypeValue}" value='%{editRulePojo.groupType}' />
```

works.

From Struts2 documentation:

> Note: For any of the tags that use lists (select probably being the most ubiquitous), which uses the OGNL list
>   notation (see the "months" example above), it should be noted that the map key created (in the months example,
>   the '01', '02', etc.) is typed. '1' is a char, '01' is a String, "1" is a String. This is important since if
>   the value returned by your "value" attribute is NOT the same type as the key in the "list" attribute, they
>   WILL NOT MATCH, even though their String values may be equivalent. If they don't match, nothing in your list
>   will be auto-selected.

Answer (score 0):

Right way to do show the selected value in drop down is to create get method in your action class :

Action Class:

```
public String getDefaultValue() {
    return "defaultVal";
}
```

JSP:

```
<s:select theme="simple" list="yourList" name="name" id="id" listKey="id" listValue="description" value="defaultValue"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!--name attribute inside select tag must be a variable in action class with getter/setter -->
<!-- test variable sets the value of selected item in action class -->
<select name="test">
    <!-- name attribute could be anything you want but value attribute must be a model class variable-->
    <s:set name="lead_string_LS_ID" value="MasterDataModel.string_LS_ID" />
        <!-- value attribute must be a list to iterate, status (an instanceof IteratorStatus will be pushed into stack upon each iteration)or result  -->
        <!-- var Name used to reference the value pushed into the Value Stack (my list contain leadSource_String_Id)-->
        <s:iterator value="leadSource_list" status="result" var="leadSource_String_Id">
                <!--#lead_string_LS_ID is value taken from <set> tag above. Note # must be in-front of the name
                    leadSource_String_Id is element specified in var of <iterator> tag  
                -->
                <s:if test='(#lead_string_LS_ID.equals(leadSource_String_Id))'>

                    <option value="<s:property value='leadSource_String_Id'/>" selected="selected">
                        <s:property value="leadSource_String_Name" />
                    </option>
                </s:if>
                <s:else>
                    <option
                        value="<s:property value='leadSource_String_Id'/>">
                        <s:property value="leadSource_String_Name" />
                    </option>
                </s:else>
        </s:iterator>
</select>
```